# Eclipse JDT adapter to java.lang.reflect

Tags: java, reflection, eclipse-jdt

I need to integrate [Eclipse JDT](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/package-frame.html) into some existing API that is based on [java.lang.reflect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-frame.html). My questions are: Is there an existing interface or adapter? What is the best way to do this? Can anyone point me to a tutorial to do this?

For instance I need to retrieve the `java.lang.reflect.Method` from a `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IMethodBinding`.

Similarly I need to get the `java.lang.Class` from a `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Type` or `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding`. I found that this can be achieved by:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(typeBinding.getBinaryName());
```

Of course this is a very simple solution that assumes that the class already exists on the classpath and is not changed via the JDT API -- so it is far from perfect. But it should be noted that these two assumptions do hold for my specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the class already exists on the classpath and is not changes substantially via the JDT API, I implemented something myself.

For instance an `IMethodBinding` can be transformed to a `Method` with the following code:

```
    IMethodBinding methodBinding = methodInvocation.resolveMethodBinding();
    Class<?> clazz = retrieveTypeClass(methodBinding.getDeclaringClass());
    Class<?>[] paramClasses = new Class<?>[methodInvocation.arguments().size()];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < methodInvocation.arguments().size(); idx++) {
        ITypeBinding paramTypeBinding = methodBinding.getParameterTypes()[idx];
        paramClasses[idx] = retrieveTypeClass(paramTypeBinding);
    }
    String methodName = methodInvocation.getName().getIdentifier();
    Method method;
    try {
        method = clazz.getMethod(methodName, paramClasses);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }

private Class<?> retrieveTypeClass(Object argument) {
    if (argument instanceof SimpleType) {
        SimpleType simpleType = (SimpleType) argument;
        return retrieveTypeClass(simpleType.resolveBinding());
    }
    if (argument instanceof ITypeBinding) {
        ITypeBinding binding = (ITypeBinding) argument;
        String className = binding.getBinaryName();
        if ("I".equals(className)) {
            return Integer.TYPE;
        }
        if ("V".equals(className)) {
            return Void.TYPE;
        }
        try {
            return Class.forName(className);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }
    if (argument instanceof IVariableBinding) {
        IVariableBinding variableBinding = (IVariableBinding) argument;
        return retrieveTypeClass(variableBinding.getType());
    }
    if (argument instanceof SimpleName) {
        SimpleName simpleName = (SimpleName) argument;
        return retrieveTypeClass(simpleName.resolveBinding());
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Retrieval of type " + argument.getClass() + " not implemented yet!");
}
```

Note that the method `retrieveTypeClass` also solves the second problem. Hope this helps anyone.